# Is anti-desitter cosmology internally consistent?

Tags: cosmology, string-theory, big-bang, string-theory-landscape, anthropic-principle

In the string landscape all known vacua that have been found have been anti-desitter (negative cosmological constant).

Is there any cosmological or physical principle that may rule out anti-desitter universes to be internally consistent? If so, this would be a way to rule out large parts of the string landscape instead of appealing to the anthropic principle? It would serve as a selection principle.

For example a negative cosmological constant would lead to a "big crunch" and therefore a future singularity. One might say that singularities in physics are a bad thing, but I can see no internal inconsistency with the Universe ending in a singularity. Equally we don't really know much about the big bang but, might it be the case that anti-desitter universes may also break down here?

Therefore I'm wondering do AdS universes break any known physical laws? Or only possibly at the big-bang and big-crunch?

For example, Hawking's No Boundary principle proports to predict a de Sitter space. And therefor presumably if one combined this with string theory, one would have to rule out any vacua with negative cosmological constant.

Well one thing I thought of is that if the Universe contracted, there might not be enough "room" for the particles to arrange themselves in ever increasing entropy, and so the concept of time and the third law of thermodynamics may break down. Indeed there might be nothing to distinguish the state at the beginning of the Universe from the end.  Indeed Hawking's black hole theory that says that black holes can never decrease in area, and yet we are saying the whole universe can decrease in volume... can this be a contradiction?

Comment: This sounds a bit like how Einstein wanted a static universe to be a principle.

Comment: @ConnorBehan I'd say it's the opposite because the universe is not static.